# bluetooth headphone can't pair

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I have LG e975 , android 4.1.2 and a bluetooth stereo headphone Pyle PHBT5  which supports A2DP.

The problem is that bluetooth can't find the device.

Is there something I can try?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Toggling bluetooth? Turning the headphones on and off? Can any other devices pair with them?

Comment: @ZnewmaN:It's ok now , I had to insist on the 6 seconds I think.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the headset into a pairing mode. According to the [manual](http://www.pyleaudio.com/sku/PHBT5S/Stereo-Bluetooth-Streaming-Wireless-Headphones-with-Built-in-Microphone---Works-with-All-Bluetooth-Enabled-Phones-and-Devices-%28Gray%29), the procedure is as follows:

- Turn the headset off
- Press and hold the MFB (Multi-Function Button) for 6 seconds until the LED flashes red and blue alternatively and you hear a beep
- Search for Bluetooth devices on your phone and select the PHBT5
- Enter 0000 as the PIN if asked
- When the pairing is successful and active the LED will flash only blue regularly

Comment: :But it can't find it . That's what I am telling :) .

Comment: Does the headset go into pairing mode correctly? Can you find other devices on your phone, or can you find the headset on another phone?

Comment: :No , it can't pair.Unfortunately I don't have other devices to test and I have  exactly the same LG phone.

Comment: :It works!I was holding the MFB button  but I released it before pairing.Now it's ok,thanks!